# Can I use 4 months old Bank statement to apply for a US B2 visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am staying in the USA on an H1B visa. I am planning to apply for a B2 visa for my parents. I have a bank statement which is 4 months old.

Can I use this to apply for the B2 visa or do I need to have to get fresh bank statement?

Answer (score 2):

Within the interview. You need to provide an evidence that is at most six months old. However, for US residents the counselor already knows that you can get your bank statement easily,  so it would look suspicious if your parents have an old statement.  Further,  it will open couple questions which is better for them just to avoid. 
BTW an ITIN would be great too if available.